# Second line of text overflowing div boundaries

Tags: php, html, css

I am stuck and can't find any solution to fix it. Second line of the text is overflowing div boundaries and there was nothing I could have done. I don't want to unlock height, set it to auto etc. cause it changes the look of the site. Clear command didn't solve the problem. Any reply with advice will be much appreciated.

scr with problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TilgJ.png

code :

|CSS Stylesheet :|

```
.spellchange{
    float: left;
    width: 840px;
    height: 41px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #cccccc;
}
.spellchangelastline{
    float: left;
    width: 840px;
    height: 41px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #cccccc;
}
.spellname{
    color: #6b645d;
    font-size: larger;
}
```

|Function PHP :|

```
class spell
{

function do_spell($spellicon, $spellname, $spelltext, $changeinpower)
{
    echo '<div class="spellchange">
    <img style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: -10px;"src="/abilities/'.$spellicon.
    '" height="32" width="32"><span class="spellname">'.$spellname.'</span> - '.$spelltext.'</div><div style="float: right;">
    <img src="/icons/'.$changeinpower.'"></div>';
    }
}
}
```

|HTML Code :|

```
<?php
    $standbehindme = new spell;
    $standbehindme->do_spell('Braum_W.png','Stand Behind Me (W)','Bonus armor and magic        resistance reduced to 15/17.5/20/22.5/25 (+10/11.5/13/14.5/16% bonus armor / mr) from   20/22.5/25/27.5/30 (+14/15.5/12/18.5/20% bonus armor / mr)','nerf.png');
?>
```

Comment: because there are no spaces in the text ?

Comment: When I add a block to a text it go down.

Comment: Is anyone else able to view the photo? or is it just me that cannot?

Comment: you set a fixed height on the box, and didn't specify an overflow condition. browsers will NOT shrink over-large text to fit, it'll just overflow. And since the 'big' text on the right is part of the line of text (inside a span), you're getting expected behavior. if you want the small text to wrap around the large text, or stay entirely to the right of it, you'll have to split the two parts into two separate/sibling dom nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the display to inline-block for the text?

```
display:inline-block;
```